# Regex text (including period) and number C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a string which contains text (that may have periods in it) followed by a number, and I'm trying to separate text from the number, the code I'm using evaluates the string char by char but is taking too long, so I've tried to use regex but I can't include the period.

If the input is A.B123, y need an array or list like: ["A.B","123"]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This `([a-zA-Z\.]*)([0-9]*)` will produce two groups: "A.B" and "123.

Here is example:

```
var parsingGroups = Regex.Match("AsB123", "([a-zA-Z.]*)([0-9]*)").Groups;
var textWithDots = parsingGroups[1].Value;
var numbers = parsingGroups[2].Value;
```

Comment: usin the code:  string pattern = "([a-zA-Z\\.]*)([0-9]*)"; result = Regex.Split("A.B123", pattern); I get ["","A.B","123","","","",""]

Comment: This supposed to be used with Regex.Match. Like Regex.Match("A.B123", "([a-zA-Z.]*)([0-9]*)").Groups, so results you are looking for will be in Group[1] and Group[2]